# Could I use Perlin Noise to generate a random musical melody?

Tags: procedural-generation, random, perlin-noise, music

Wouod it be possible to use a perlin noise function that generated random musical melodies? It would need parameters directing range and key changes. If so, with what platform/language?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Nice to listen to? Unlikely, but if you want to experiment I would recommend you to stick to the major pentatonic scale (C, G, D, A, E). Platform/language? Off-topic on this website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with game development.

Answer (score 1):

You could, but you probably shouldn't. A simple system will likely have too much random variation to sound pleasing.

There is extensive research into algorithmic/procedural generation of music and I recommend you search for some of it.

Specifically you might look into Markov Chains and some of the work being done with neural networks.